# ffmpeg convert TS video file to raw rgb32 video file

Tags: ffmpeg, rgb, yuv

I have a transport steam file containing H.264 video and would like to extract the video stream to a file containing raw uncompressed RGB32 video frames. So the H.264 video would need to be decoded and converted to RGB32 frames that would be dumped into a file.

Is there a ffmpeg command that would do this, or any other method?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Sorry. I was lead here by other command line questions about ffmpeg.

Comment: Yes, it's a common problem - the `ffmpeg` tag is for questions about *programming* with the the ffmpeg API and libraries. General user-level (i.e. non-programming) questions about `ffmpeg` are off-topic and typically belong on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FFmpeg command line,

```
ffmpeg -i in.ts -pix_fmt rgba -c:v rawvideo -map 0:v -f rawvideo in-rgba.raw
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error "[NULL @ 000000000031dc00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'in-rgba.raw'
in-rgba.raw: Invalid argument
Exact command line was
ffmpeg.exe -i 00023.MTS -pix_fmt rgba -c:v rawvideo -map 0:v in-rgba.raw